# C++ "Hello World.exe" crashes - "Hello World.exe has stopped working." when used in command prompt

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, dll, crash

I've started learning C++ and wrote a "Hello World"-Program. When i try to run it in command prompt, it crashes and gives me a windows message saying "Hello World.exe has stopped working.".

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string response;

    std::cout << "Hallo Welt\n";
    std::cin >> response;
    std::cout << "User: " << response;

    return(0);
}
```

I'm using Eclipse IDE and MinGW as compiler. I've already set the path of MinGW/bin in the environment variables. After i copied all dll's form the MinGW/bin directory into the folder of the Hello World.exe the program worked smoothly. So it seems that whatever it is that needs those dll's cannot access them properly. I'd like to spare me the hassle of copying the dll's for every project i create. Is there any way i could work around that?

I'm not really confident about my computer and programming terminology yet so the description might seem a bit rough - help is still greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: Adding `-static -static-libgcc` might help with the DLL moving, but in my experience, missing one is accompanied with Windows giving a clear error when you try to run the program.

Comment: Unless you have good reasons to use MinGW, I'd move to Visual C++ Express, which is also free and lets you program using the native libraries.

Comment: You need to statically link or look into getting a correct LOADLIBRARYPATH in the shell/environment you run the command from.

Answer (score 8):

The following [instructions](https://orfe.princeton.edu/help/article-296) did the work for me so I add them here for future reference as this problem took quite some time.

> **Prerequisites**
>
> - Windows 7 64-bit with all current Software Updates applied.
> - MinGW 0.5-beta–20120426–1 or later.
> - Java JRE 1.7 or higher.
> - Eclipse
>
> **Installation Steps**
>
> 1. Install the Java JRE from Oracle.
> 2. Install MinGW. During the Select Components step, select “C++
>      Compiler” and “MSYS Basic System” for installation.
> 3. Download Eclipse for C++ Developers.
> 4. Extract the Eclipse archive downloaded to your Downloads folder.
> 5. Open the Eclipse application found in the extracted Eclipse
>      folder.[2]
> 6. Test your Eclipse install by creating a new C++ Project from the
>      File and New menu.
> 7. Select “Hello World C++ Project” under Executable for the Project
>      Type, and MinGW GCC for the Toolchain of your New C++ Project. Type
>      a Project Name and click the Finish button.
> 8. **Add “-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++” as Linker flags for your new
>      project. This text should be added to the Linker flags field, which
>      can be found by right-clicking on the new Project in the Project
>      Explorer and clicking on Properties. Under the Project Properties,
>      expand the C/C++ Build menu and click on Settings. Under the Tool
>      Settings tab, expand the MinGW C++ Linker menu and click on
>      Miscellaneous. Add the text to the Linker flags field, then click
>      the Apply button.**
> 9. Click Build Project under the Project menu, then click Run under the
>      Run menu.
> 10. Confirm you have a functioning developer environment by viewing the
>       output of the Console.

Please note that **step 8** is the one that solves the problem.

**Note:** You should also copy `freeglut.dll` in the directory where your `.exe` is located.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem. And what i found is that there might be different versions of the same DLL on my Path. So i simply moved my C:\MinGW\bin path from the end of the Path list to the front and now it's working. But maybe this solution breaks some other software that relies on the other version of the DLL file.