# c++ is not working,but c is working in eclipse kepler

Tags: c++, eclipse

I've downloaded and installed the latest Eclipse kepler,this is working well of c, but c++ is not working after run a code ( successful build), I just get a window saying "hello.exe has stopped working", or whatever the name of my program. I can't find any helpful answers online, I've tried what I've seen. I'm using Windows 8.1, Eclipse kepler (latest version), and MinGW. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

That [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27710549/6060256) might help you. It seems to be an issue with DLL. I share it for posterity, thaks to his author.

> **Prerequisites**
>
> - Windows 7 64-bit with all current Software Updates applied.
> - MinGW 0.5-beta–20120426–1 or later.
> - Java JRE 1.7 or higher.
> - Eclipse
>
> **Installation Steps**
>
> 1. Install the Java JRE from Oracle.
> 2. Install MinGW. During the Select Components step, select “C++
>      Compiler” and “MSYS Basic System” for installation.
> 3. Download Eclipse for C++ Developers.
> 4. Extract the Eclipse archive downloaded to your Downloads folder.
> 5. Open the Eclipse application found in the extracted Eclipse
>      folder.[2]
> 6. Test your Eclipse install by creating a new C++ Project from the
>      File and New menu.
> 7. Select “Hello World C++ Project” under Executable for the Project
>      Type, and MinGW GCC for the Toolchain of your New C++ Project. Type
>      a Project Name and click the Finish button.
> 8. **Add “-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++” as Linker flags for your new
>      project. This text should be added to the Linker flags field, which
>      can be found by right-clicking on the new Project in the Project
>      Explorer and clicking on Properties. Under the Project Properties,
>      expand the C/C++ Build menu and click on Settings. Under the Tool
>      Settings tab, expand the MinGW C++ Linker menu and click on
>      Miscellaneous. Add the text to the Linker flags field, then click
>      the Apply button.**
> 9. Click Build Project under the Project menu, then click Run under the
>      Run menu.
> 10. Confirm you have a functioning developer environment by viewing the
>       output of the Console.

**Note**: You should also copy `freeglut.dll` in the directory where your `.exe` is located.