# Building c++ program using eclipse neon gives me "cc1plus.exe" has stopped working error

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am just trying to run a basic hello world c++ program that was recommended by eclipse (file->new->c++ project-> "Hello World C++ Project" and am reaching errors at every level. At first the build would give me a "make file" and "g++" not found but then I installed minGW/gcc/minSYS using the "mingw-get" installer provided at this address http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started on my computer, fixing that issue. But now when I try and build this or any other c++ program I get a pop-up saying "cc1plus.exe has stopped working" whether I build the entire workspace or just the program. Can anyone explain what might be going wrong? I've reinstalled both eclipse and minGW by deleting their folders and starting again but nothing seems to be working!

Using
Windows 8(64 bit)
Eclipse Neon 4.6.1

Comment: I see!! Is there any way to make that standard in all c++ projects I create?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ "Hello World.exe" crashes - "Hello World.exe has stopped working." when used in command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693240/c-hello-world-exe-crashes-hello-world-exe-has-stopped-working-when-used)